# application or way to split column of data into named text files?

Tags: sql, list, text, split

I have a list I created from a query in SSMS that consists of 50,000+ 9 digit numbers.  I was wondering if anyone knows a way to automatically split the list into groups of 700 and save them with similar names that ascended in order ie booklist01.txt, booklist02.txt, booklist03.txt... etc.  The lists need to be output eventually as .txt files.  I figure there has to be an app out there that does this but also bet someone knows so cool macro!

Comment: As far as the splitting up part goes, you can use `LIMIT 700` to get `700` items. You can use `OFFSET` to offset your results.

Comment: `LIMIT` belongs to MySql, as Rob's using SSMS I assume we are talking about a MS SQL Server, whose command is `TOP`.

Comment: There are some applications for text file splitting available if you google them, but you could also easily write some console application passing the filename as a command line argument, to fulfill your specific needs, if you are going to do this frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the list is a list of rows in a table. If that's the case, then you can produce a `file_id` by dividing the row number by 700, as in:

```
with x as (
select
    n, row_number() over(order by n) as rn
  from my_table
)
select n, rn, round(rn / 700, 0, 1) as file_id from x
```

Comment: You are missing the order in the `over()`, and you cannot have a `order by` in a view, like this `with` block. Anyway, after fixing this will just list the records with a file number next to it, I don't think this is what Rob needs.